# What is the right way to attach multiple images to a post? [Django]

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am working on a webcomics platform, and I need to allow users to upload multiple images in one post.

- Ideally - keep it as simple as possible, so that a person wouldn't have to refresh the page to upload each image, or create and save a post before adding images.
- If a user could delete or reorder images it would be nice.
- Also, I need to make it scalable, so that I wouldn't have problems with it later.

Can you give me advice on how to do it properly?

Should images have their own model, and be connected to the post with foreign key? (not sure if this makes sense, seems kinda ugly)

Or should I just keep a list of image urls in the some type of field on a post model, and then create some sort of cdn and upload it there?

Any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: html5 or non html5 based approach, which approach r u looking for?

Comment: @AnilKumar html5 I guess...

Comment: then you can refer https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload and https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html#input.file.attrs.multiple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about scale then you need to figure out what the best practice is for serving images.

I would recommend that you use S3 to serve your static files (this will include your user-uploaded files too). Follow [this tutorial](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/) which shows you how to set this up from scratch.

Now, digging into your schema, you will need both a `Post` and `PostImage` model:

**models.py:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()

class PostImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='<path_from_s3_tutorial>'
    )
    width_x = models.IntegerField()
    width_y = models.IntegerField()

    # Foreign Key to Post
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', null=True, blank=True)
```

Then when you will need to create a class in **forms.py** that uses an [Inline Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) which allows you to upload multiple images when you create a post, as below:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Post, PostImage
>>> from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
>>>
>>> PostImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Post, PostImage, fields=('image',))
>>> post = Post.objects.get(id=13)
>>> formset = PostImageFormSet(instance=post)
```

You will then validate your formset in your view like so:

**views.py**

```
def create_post(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    PostImageInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Post, PostImage, fields=('image',))
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = PostImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        formset = PostImageFormSet(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'manage_books.html', {'formset': formset})
```

*Note: Most of this example was modified from the one in the Django docs which I linked above.*